# PHP time() in 'if statements' not passed to MySql query?

Tags: php, mysql, time, if-statement

```
if($_SESSION['periode']){

    if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Today'){
    $xdate = time() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time();
    }
    if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Yesterday'){
    $xdate = time() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'This week'){
    $xdate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Older'){
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    else{
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time();
    }
}
else {
$xdate = 0;
$ydate = time();
}

$tweets = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE content LIKE '%$search%' 
AND content LIKE '%$region%' 
AND time BETWEEN $xdate AND $ydate ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

The problem: all messages are selected from the database and not only those between $xdate and $ydate.

If I manually fill in a unix time period in the else statement however (and don't define $_SESSION['periode']) the correct messages are picked out of the DB. What's going on??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Older'){
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
else{
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time();
    }
```

This code will always set $ydate to time() and $xdate to 0 if $_SESSION['periode'] is not 'Older', because this else is related to just above if.
You need to use elseif rather than if

code must be

```
if($_SESSION['periode']){

    if($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Today'){
    $xdate = time() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time();
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Yesterday'){
    $xdate = time() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['periode'] == 'This week'){
    $xdate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $ydate = time() - (2 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    elseif($_SESSION['periode'] == 'Older'){
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    }
    else{
    $xdate = 0;
    $ydate = time();
    }
}
else {
$xdate = 0;
$ydate = time();
}
```

Comment: I have to use elseif for yesterday/this week/older of course! Wow, that I didn't see that... Thanks!!